# div not scrolling when href link is clicked

Tags: html, anchor, hyperlink

I have a website that has a bunch of pictures that you can scroll horizontally and I also have thumbnails that I would like to have be able to click on them to scroll to the desired picture.
I have read all about scrolling to an id using an anchor however I still can not get this to work..
I will attach my code if someone could please help me out that would be amazing.

Thanks

```
    <!--Start Main Content-->
<div style="width:1100px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden;">
    <div style="width:6716px; height:600px; ">
        <!--<a id="section_1"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait05_lg.jpg'); width:465px; height:700px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>-->

        <a id="section_2"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:465px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch2">
                    <img src="images/more.png" width="25" height="25" />
                    <span><img src="../images/blog.png"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant2">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor2">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="section_3"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait07_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:498px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch3">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant3">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor3">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="section_4"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait04_lg.jpg'); width:416px; height:643px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="section_5"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait01_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:517px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="section_6"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait02_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:465px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="section_7"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait03_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:527px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="section_8"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait08_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:465px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="section_9"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait09_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:399px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="section_10"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/fashion01_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:465px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <a id="section_11"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/fashion02_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:481px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!--<a id="section_12"></a>
            <div id="picture" style="background-image:url('../images/Photography/Fashion/fashion03_lg.jpg'); width:700px; height:879px;">
                <div class="more" id="couch4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="plant4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>

                <div class="more" id="monitor4">
                    <img src="images/more.png" />
                    <span>Test</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        -->

    </div>

</div>

<div id="index-text">
    <div class="shadowTop"></div>

    <div id="text" style="width:900px;">
    <a href="#section_1"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_2"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_3"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_4"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_5"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_6"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_7"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_8"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_9"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_10"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_11"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="#section_12"><img src="../images/Photography/Fashion/Portrait06_lg.jpg" width="50" height="50" border="0" /></a><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the name attribute in your  tags for the bookmarks rather than id.

```
<a name="section_11"></a>
```

Comment: I have tried that and when I make the <a id into <a name it still doesn't work. All that happens is which ever link I click it scrolls me all the way to the right and to the top of the page

Comment: it works if I take it away the <a name tags and just make each picture have its own unique id. How ever is there a way to make it so that it doesn't jump to the top of the page every time I click on a link

Comment: You need to make sure there are no duplicate ID's at all in the page.  Jumping to the top of the page is strange, does this happen after the page moves to the location of the bookmark?  If you want more help please update your code above with your new changes

Comment: this code is up to date and I have checked all all of my ID's to make sure there is no duplicates and it jumps to the end of the horizontal div and scrolls to the top of the page